# PowerShell: Returning data from multiple arrays at the same time

Tags: arrays, powershell

Alright, folks.  Another one I'm not entirely sure is possible.  I've looked around and haven't seen anything that works (or if I have, I didn't realize it).

Essentially, I have two arrays...

```
$x = @(a,d,b,c)

$y = @(alice,bob,chuck,dave)
```

...the former being pre-populated, the latter being generated by user input; they will always be the same length as each other.

I want to essentially do `foreach ($x in $x) {echo "$x is assigned to $y")`

with the results being something like:

> a is assigned to alice
>
> d is assigned to bob
>
> b is assigned to chuck
>
> c is assigned to dave

The problem is that I have *no idea* how to go about that, if it's even possible.   While it's not 100% necessary for my script, it would significantly shorten what I have to have written and would allow for extending the parameters of the script.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** *Selected answer was selected because while others are largely the same, it is a bit more legible and just seems more comfortable to use*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ordinary `for` loop instead of `foreach` like so,

```
$x = @('a','d','b','c')
$y = @('alice','bob','chuck','dave')

if($x.Length -ne $y.Length) { 
    # TODO: What to do if user input is missing assignees?
} else {
    for($i=0;$i -ne $x.Length; ++$i) { "{0} -> {1}" -f $x[$i], $y[$i] }
}

Output
a -> alice
d -> bob
b -> chuck
c -> dave
```

Comment: Thanks!  If I'm understanding this right, and needed to add a third array (still same length) to it, I'd just do...     `{ "{0} -> {1}. {3}" -f $x[i], $y[$i], $z[$i] }`

Comment: @MrSchism Almost. Composite formating uses 0-based index, so the 3rd term ought to be `{2}`, not `{3}`.

Comment: Yeah, I know it has to use a 0 index value.  Truth be told, I didn't even notice I made that mistake.  I was going through my script while typing this and forgot to step-down the number.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of ways of doing that in one line of code.
So considering your code:

```
$x = @("a","d","b","c");
$y = @("alice","bob","chuck","dave");
```

This works if your items in $x are all distinct:

```
$x | ForEach-Object { "$_ is assigned to $($y[$x.IndexOf($_)])" };
```

You can also shorten the ForEach-Object to just a percent. They mean the same thing:

```
$x | % { "$_ is assigned to $($y[$x.IndexOf($_)])" };
```

If your items are not distinct (or you just want to avoid indexing for no reason), you can add another block to initialize an indexer variable, like so:

```
$x | % { $i = 0 } { "$_ is assigned to $($y[$i])"; ++$i };
```

Thought the subject was interesting so also dropped a post on it:

https://tangodude.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/powershell-different-ways-of-looping-indexing/

Answer (score 0):

Shortest I could get it down to is:

```
$i = 0; $x | % { "$_ is assigned to $($y[$i++])"}
```